# Why is a UIView's frame correctly resized on rotation screen if held by an UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uikit

Given this example:

When I add a view programatically and set its frame...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let subview = UIView()
        subview.backgroundColor = .red
        subview.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

[image]

It doesn't get resized when I rotate the screen

[image]

However, when I add a view that is generated by a view controller like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let subview = UIViewController().view!
        subview.backgroundColor = .red
        subview.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

It gets resized when I rotate the screen.

[image]

What is happening? Why those two views handle trait collection changes differently?

Does it implies that I **should** use constraints no matter what (even in custom presentation modal transitions and push navigation transitions, on which Apple's doc seems to recommend to use frames?)

Comment: You almost **certainly** want to be using auto-layout and constraints, rather than setting `.frame`. Show a complete, minimal example of what you're trying to do. See [mre].

Comment: Problem being that using transitions (for push navigations or modal presentation) it looks to be better to use frames rather than constrains (given Apple doc and other example I found on the internet). It does work using constraints, but it seems to be a bad practice in this very specific example. Nevertheless I was wondering why the resizing occured only when the view is generated by a view controller

Comment: It's tough to say what might be happening - and to offer help - without being able to run your code and see what's going on.

Comment: Just edited it. Removed the navigation part. It can be reproduced in 5 minutes on a simulator

Comment: Can you post a link to Apple's docs that say it's better to use frames in this case?

Comment: Sure. This Apple doc using `UIPresentationController`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller. There's a method that one can override that is `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`. After some tests, even if I dont override this var and try to place my presented view in my container using constraints, it doesnt take them into account. 
Looked "weird" to use frame for one part (the presented view) and constraints for the other views I am trying to add in the container. This is my intuition, I maybe wrong not to mix those 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very odd...

```
let subviewFromVC = UIViewController().view!
```

You are creating a **new** instance of a `UIViewController()` (***NOT*** related to the *current* view controller), and grabbing a reference to its `.view`.

Then you add that view as a subview, and set its frame.

The "base" view of a `UIViewController` comes with:

```
.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

so it "auto-resizes" ...

However, when you do this:

```
let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .red
subview.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(subview)
```

By default, `subview` is created with:

```
.autoresizingMask = []
```

so it ***doesn't*** "auto-resize" ...

If you want `subview` to auto-resize based on the frame you set, you need to set that mask:

```
let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .red
subview.frame = view.frame

subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

view.addSubview(subview)
```

If you are creating a new subview - or, probably, multiple subviews - that auto-resize and automatically adjust their positions, you will need a combination of the various `.autoresizingMask` flags:

```
.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight,
.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin,
.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin,
```

Without seeing the UI layout you're going for, can't offer much else -- but that should at least get you on your way.

---

**Edit** - *mixing `frame` and constraints...*

The reason we see something like `viewToPresent.frame.origin.x =` in a custom `UIPresentationController` is because **that** view is instantiated with `.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]`. So, to "slide it in from the left" for example, we'd animate it along these lines:

```
viewToPresent.frame.origin.x = -viewToPresent.frame.width

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    viewToPresent.frame.origin.x = 0.0
})
```

That can also be done with constraints, but for this use-case setting frame values is (perhaps) easier.

For the "dimming view," though, it would seem to make more sense to use constraints, since its size/position won't be animated.

What often is not obvious is that:

```
someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

does ***Not*** mean auto-layout is not being used... it means that the view's `.autoresizingMask` *is being translated into constraints*.

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I wanted to know. I couldn't figure it out by inspecting those view in the debugger. It seems I've been using constraints for a long time! 
Thank you very much

Comment: "You are creating a new instance of a UIViewController() (NOT related to the current view controller), and grabbing a reference to its .view" 
Thats from the same tutorial I was trying to follow: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller. I couldn't figure out why the `dimmingView` was not resizing properly, whereas the presented view (grabbed from a view controller) did resize. That is why I tried

Comment: @Olympiloutre - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer for a little more explanation.

Comment: yup thank you for the edit. I do know about the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, I just forgot how autoresizing mask work in my example. When I say that I don't want to mix constraints and frames (with autoresizing mask) it is just because it looks like code smell to me to use both in the same class. It would be like using nib files and add programmatically add views in `viewDidLoad` for instance. Just a personal preference. Thanks for the edit